# Android Wear Watch Face - INVALID_ACCOUNT when trying to connect to Google Services API

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, wear-os, google-fit

I have a watch face which I am trying to connect to the Google Play Services to get the user's heart rate data. I have created an OAuth 2.0 client ID and have followed the guide.

Here is my setup code from OnCreate():

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Wearable.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
        .build();
googleApiClient.connect();
```

I am triggering the OnConnectionFailed() listener. here is the ConnectionResult:

```
ConnectionResult{statusCode=INVALID_ACCOUNT, resolution=null, message=null}
```

My full class can be found here: http://pastebin.com/qNuvRY3F

I've either missed something or I am doing all this in the wrong place. Probably both. I may need to get this data from my mobile device and send this data over via the DataLayer, which I am still trying to figure out how to do in a background service, which to send alongside battery info, weather data etc.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error [`INVALID_ACCOUNT`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#INVALID_ACCOUNT) means that the client attempt to connect service using **invalid account** name specified.

Error code are used by the **GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener** helper class. Error are generated by the Google Play Service server when something does not work. Working with Google Play will be an important area for `Wear` developers to master.

Here's a related SO ticket: [Issue with Google Fit API on Android Wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295189/issue-with-google-fit-api-on-android-wear)

Comment: Thanks. I figured out I was trying to trigger a sign-in to google via a wear device. I moved my code into a phone service which then requests a sign in, which I then launch an activity to trigger the google sign in dialog.

Comment: What does that mean? Invalid Account Name? Is the email invalid? I have Game Play installed with a valid email, but still getting this issue.