# How to use Google Fit API on Wearables (Sony Smartwatch)

Tags: android, google-fit, sony-smartwatch

I`ve been trying to use the Google Fit API for counting steps in my App for the Sony Smartwatch 3. I can't find any basic step-by-step tutorial for using the API.

**So my question:** does somebody know any tutorials or similar where I can look up how to use it?

Comment: Did you look at the Samples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace

Answer (score 0):

I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) of Google Fit can give you the basic or the first step that you need to do in order to connect the Google Fit API in to a Wearable Device.

For the different API from Google FIT, this [page](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples) of the documentation can give you a sample code on how to use the following APIs:

- AndroidWatchFace
- BasicSensorsApi
- BasicRecordingApi
- BasicHistoryApi
- BasicHistorySessions

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295189/issue-with-google-fit-api-on-android-wear) and these tutorials:

- [How To Develop Your First Google Fit App](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-develop-your-first-google-fit-app/how-to/2015/02/19).
- [How To: Use GoogleFit API](http://orange.dataart.com/how-to-use-googlefit-api/)