# Reading the Heart Rate from wear os watch using Google fit from a paired app

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, android-wear-2.0

I am trying to get Heart Rate from my Android wear-os watch using Google fit api.
Both my watch and android devices are paired.

I've tried 2 approaches:

1) From Android app, connect to google fit and scan for data sources. But it will only detect the step sensor on my android device, without the paired watch sensors.

```
mFitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
 .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
 .addScope(Fitness.SCOPE_BODY_READ)
 .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Fitness client connected");
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Fitness client suspended");
  }
 })
 .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Fitness Connection failed");
  }
 })
 .build();
mFitnessClient.connect();

DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
 .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
 .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
 .build();

ResultCallback < DataSourcesResult > dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback < DataSourcesResult > () {
 @Override
 public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
  for (DataSource dataSource: dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {

  }
 }
};

Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mFitnessClient, dataSourceRequest)
 .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);
```

2) Read directly from the watch as a wear-os app. But if I define Fitness.SENSORS_API, I tend to get onConnectionFailed, with Error Code 5 (INVALID_ACCOUNT).

```
mFitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
 .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
 .addScope(Fitness.SCOPE_BODY_READ)
 .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Connected to fitness API");

  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

  }
 })
 .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
  }
 })
 .build();
mFitnessClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) From Android app, connect to google fit and scan for data sources. But it will only detect the step sensor on my android device, without the paired watch sensors.

You can get Heart Rate using **RecordingClient**

Android 10 introduces the android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION runtime permission for apps that need to detect the user's step count or classify the user's physical activity.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        PERMISSIONS,
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
            }
        } else {
            fintessConnection();

        }


public void fintessConnection() {
        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();
        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                    this, // your activity
                    GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                    fitnessOptions);
        } else {
            accessGoogleFit();
        }
    }
```

> Subscribing to Heart Rate/BPM:

```
Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                });
```

> Retrieving BPM:

```
 DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .bucketByTime(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();


        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readData(readRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess()");

                        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResponse.getBuckets()) {
                            Log.e("History", "Data returned for Data type: " + bucket.getDataSets());

                            List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                            for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                                showDataSet(dataSet);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataReadResponse> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete()");
                    }
                });
```

2) Read directly from the watch as a wear-os app. But if I define Fitness.SENSORS_API, I tend to get onConnectionFailed, with Error Code 5 (INVALID_ACCOUNT).

Before you can invoke methods from the Google Fit APIs, you must connect to one or more of the following API clients, which are part of Google Play services:

1. Sensors Client
2. Recording Client
3. History Client
4. Sessions Client
5. Goals Client
6. BLE Client
7. Config Client

First Connect to one of above API from Handheld device then you can invoke API in Watch.[Detailed Answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28327936/4468665)