# Wear OS Google Fit Recording API Subscribe to DataType error INVALID_ACCOUNT

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, wear-os, google-fit

I'm getting this error when running when trying to subscribe on to DataTypes for Recording on WearOS:
`error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null`

I'm basing this WearOS version heavily off of https://github.com/android/fit-samples/tree/main/BasicHistorySessionsKotlin

My Setup:
MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
Android Studio: 4.1.1

Physical Device:
TicWatch Pro
System Version : H
Wear OS by Google: 2.19
Android security patch level: June 1, 2020

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<package_name>">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle wear module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<package_name>"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'

    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/session_start"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="start"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStop"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/session_end"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="stop"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package <package_name>

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.wear.ambient.AmbientModeSupport
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessActivities
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessOptions
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSource
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Session
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Subscription
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataSourcesRequest
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

enum class FitActionRequestCode {
    INSERT_AND_VERIFY_SESSION
}

enum class RecordingType {
    SUBSCRIBE,
    UNSUBSCRIBE
}

enum class SessionType {
    START,
    STOP
}

class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider {

    var mTextView: TextView? = null
    var activityContext: Context? = null
    var running: Boolean? = false

    var btnStart: Button? = null
    var btnStop: Button? = null

    enum class AmbientType {
        EXIT, ENTER
    }
    
    private val TAG: String = "RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR"

    var currentSession: Session? = null

    private fun performActionForRequestCode(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) = when (requestCode) {
        FitActionRequestCode.INSERT_AND_VERIFY_SESSION -> startRecording()
    }

    private fun fitSignIn(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fitSignIn")
        if (oAuthPermissionsApproved()) {
            performActionForRequestCode(requestCode)
        } else {
            requestCode.let {
                GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        it.ordinal,
                        getGoogleAccount(), fitnessOptions)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun oAuthPermissionsApproved() = GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(getGoogleAccount(), fitnessOptions)

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when (resultCode) {
            AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK -> {
                val postSignInAction = FitActionRequestCode.values()[requestCode]
                performActionForRequestCode(postSignInAction)
            }
            else -> oAuthErrorMsg(requestCode, resultCode)
        }
    }

    private fun oAuthErrorMsg(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int) {
        val message = """
            There was an error signing into Fit. Check the troubleshooting section of the README
            for potential issues.
            Request code was: $requestCode
            Result code was: $resultCode
        """.trimIndent()
        Log.e(TAG, message)
    }

    private val fitnessOptions: FitnessOptions by lazy {
        FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_SPEED, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE) //comment to fix
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_POINTS, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_MOVE_MINUTES, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .build()
    }

    private val dataSourceRequest = DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT,
                        DataType.TYPE_SPEED,
                        DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM,
                        DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE,
                        DataType.TYPE_HEART_POINTS,
                        DataType.TYPE_MOVE_MINUTES,
                        DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA,
                        DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA,
                        DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED) //should be used if any other data source is used in generating the data.
                .build()

    private fun getGoogleAccount() = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)

    //Documentation:
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //Success Start Flow
    //start() -> startRecording() -> successRecording() -> startSession() -> successSession()

    //Success Stop Flow
    //stop() -> stopSession() -> successSession() -> stopRecording() -> successRecording()

    //Fail Start Recording Flow
    //start() -> startRecording() -> failRecording() -> stopRecording()

    //Fail Start Session Flow
    //start() -> startRecording() -> successRecording() -> startSession() -> failSession() -> stopRecording()

    //Fail Stop Session Flow
    //stop() -> stopSession() -> failSession() -> stopRecording()

    //Fail Stop Recording Flow
    //stop() -> stopSession() -> successSession() -> stopRecording()
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    fun start(view: android.view.View){
        Log.i(TAG, "start()")

        checkPermissionsAndRun(FitActionRequestCode.INSERT_AND_VERIFY_SESSION)
    }

    fun stop(view: android.view.View){
        Log.i(TAG, "stop()")

        stopSession()
    }

    private fun failRecording(type: RecordingType, errs: List<Exception>){
        for (err in errs){
            Log.e(TAG, "failRecording ${type.name} ${err.message}")
        }

        //ignore error here to prevent infinite loop, list still recording
        listRecordingSubscriptions()
    }

    private fun successRecording(type: RecordingType, errs: List<Exception>){
        if(errs.isNotEmpty()){
            failRecording(type, errs)
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "successRecording ${type.name}")
        when (type) {
            RecordingType.SUBSCRIBE -> {
                startSession()
            }
            RecordingType.UNSUBSCRIBE -> {
                running = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun failSession(type: SessionType, err: Exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "failSession ${type.name} ${err.message}")
        stopRecording()
    }

    private fun successSession(type: SessionType, session: Session){
        Log.e(TAG, "successSession ${type.name}")
        when (type) {
            SessionType.START -> {
                btnStart?.visibility = View.GONE
                btnStop?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                running = true
                currentSession = session
            }
            SessionType.STOP -> {
                currentSession = null
                stopRecording()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startRecording() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startRecording()")

        val returnExceptions = mutableListOf<Exception>()

        val dataTypeLen = dataSourceRequest.dataTypes.size
        for ((i, dt) in dataSourceRequest.dataTypes.withIndex()) {
            Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
                    .subscribe(dt)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d(TAG, "i $i dataType: $dt, subscribe success")
                        if(i >= dataTypeLen - 1){
                            successRecording(RecordingType.SUBSCRIBE, returnExceptions)
                        }
                     }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? -> run {
                        val e2 = Exception("i $i dataType: $dt, error ${e?.message}")
                        returnExceptions.add(e2)
                        if(i >= dataTypeLen - 1){
                            failRecording(RecordingType.SUBSCRIBE, returnExceptions)
                        }
                    } }
        }
    }

    private fun stopRecording() {
        Log.i(TAG, "stopRecording()")

        val returnExceptions = mutableListOf<Exception>()

        val dataTypeLen = dataSourceRequest.dataTypes.size
        for ((i, dt) in dataSourceRequest.dataTypes.withIndex()) {
            Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
                    .unsubscribe(dt)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d(TAG, "i $i dataType: $dt, unsubscribe success")
                        if(i >= dataTypeLen - 1){
                            successRecording(RecordingType.UNSUBSCRIBE, returnExceptions)
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? -> run {
                        val e2 = Exception("i $i dataType: $dt, error ${e?.message}")
                        returnExceptions.add(e2)
                        if(i >= dataTypeLen - 1){
                            failRecording(RecordingType.UNSUBSCRIBE, returnExceptions)
                        }
                    } }
        }
    }

    private fun listRecordingSubscriptions(){
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
                .listSubscriptions()
                .addOnSuccessListener { subscriptions: List<Subscription> ->
                    for (sc in subscriptions) {
                        val dt = sc.dataType
                        Log.i(TAG, "Active subscription for data type: ${dt?.name}")
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? -> Log.e(TAG, "There was a problem listing subscriptions, error $e") }
    }

    private fun startSession() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startSession")

        val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
        val now = Date()
        cal.time = now

        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()

        // 1. Subscribe to fitness data (see Recording Fitness Data)
        // 2. Create a session object
        // (provide a name, identifier, description, activity and start time)

        val sessionName = "RunFitGame session $now"
        val identifier = uuid.toString()
        val description = "RunFitGame RUNNING session $now"
        val startTime = cal.timeInMillis

        val session: Session = Session.Builder()
                .setName(sessionName)
                .setIdentifier(identifier)
                .setDescription(description)
                .setActivity(FitnessActivities.RUNNING)
                .setStartTime(startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()

        // 3. Use the Sessions client to start a session:
        Fitness.getSessionsClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
                .startSession(session)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    successSession(SessionType.START, session)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? -> run {
                    failSession(SessionType.START, e!!)
                } }
    }

    private fun stopSession(){
        Log.i(TAG, "stopSession")

        // 1. Invoke the SessionsClient with the session identifier
                Fitness.getSessionsClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
                .stopSession(currentSession?.identifier)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    successSession(SessionType.STOP, currentSession!!)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? -> run {
                    failSession(SessionType.STOP, e!!)
                } }
    }

    override fun getAmbientCallback(): AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallback =
            object : AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallback() {

                /** If the display is low-bit in ambient mode. i.e. it requires anti-aliased fonts.  */
                private var mIsLowBitAmbient = false

                /**
                 * If the display requires burn-in protection in ambient mode, rendered pixels need to be
                 * intermittently offset to avoid screen burn-in.
                 */
                private var mDoBurnInProtection = false

                override fun onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails: Bundle?) {
                    // Handle entering ambient mode
                    Log.d("wear/MainActivity.kt", "onEnterAmbient")

                    mIsLowBitAmbient =
                            ambientDetails!!.getBoolean(AmbientModeSupport.EXTRA_LOWBIT_AMBIENT, false)
                    mDoBurnInProtection =
                            ambientDetails.getBoolean(AmbientModeSupport.EXTRA_BURN_IN_PROTECTION, false)

                    println("mIsLowBitAmbient $mIsLowBitAmbient, mDoBurnInProtection $mDoBurnInProtection")
                    switchAmbient(AmbientType.ENTER)
                }

                override fun onExitAmbient() {
                    // Handle exiting ambient mode
                    Log.d("wear/MainActivity.kt", "onExitAmbient")
                    switchAmbient(AmbientType.EXIT)
                }

                override fun onUpdateAmbient() {
                    // Update the content
                    Log.d("wear/MainActivity.kt", "onUpdateAmbient")
                }
            }

    private fun switchAmbient(at: AmbientType) {

        when (at) {
            AmbientType.ENTER -> {
                mTextView?.text = getString(R.string.ambient_enter)
                mTextView?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,
                        R.color.lightGrey))
            }
            AmbientType.EXIT -> {
                mTextView?.text = getString(R.string.ambient_exit)
                mTextView?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,
                        R.color.green))
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Declare an ambient mode controller, which will be used by
     * the activity to determine if the current mode is ambient.
     */
    private lateinit var ambientController: AmbientModeSupport.AmbientController


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ambientController = AmbientModeSupport.attach(this)

        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.text)
        activityContext = this

        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStart)
        btnStop = findViewById(R.id.btnStop)

        btnStart?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun checkPermissionsAndRun(fitActionRequestCode: FitActionRequestCode) {
        Log.i(TAG, "checkPermissionsAndRun")
        if (permissionApproved()) {
            fitSignIn(fitActionRequestCode)
        } else {
            requestRuntimePermissions(fitActionRequestCode)
        }
    }

    private val runningQOrLater =
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

    private fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean = permissions.all {
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun permissionApproved(): Boolean {
        Log.i(TAG, "permissionApproved")
        return if (runningQOrLater) {
            hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS)
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "runningQOrLater, permissionApproved true")
            true
        }
    }

    private fun requestRuntimePermissions(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) {
        Log.i(TAG, "requestRuntimePermissions")
        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        requestCode.let {
                Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission")
                // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
                // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
                // previously and checked "Never ask again".
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS),
                        requestCode.ordinal)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult")
        when {
            grantResults.isEmpty() -> {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request
                // is cancelled and you receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult User interaction was cancelled.")
            }
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                // Permission was granted.
                val fitActionRequestCode = FitActionRequestCode.values()[requestCode]
                fitSignIn(fitActionRequestCode)
            }
            else -> {

                Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult Permission denied")
                // Permission denied.

                // In this Activity we've chosen to notify the user that they
                // have rejected a core permission for the app since it makes the Activity useless.
                // We're communicating this message in a Snackbar since this is a sample app, but
                // core permissions would typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

                // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
                // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
                // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
                // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
                // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Sat Oct 24 19:12:41 MST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

How im getting my debug oauth client id:
`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass <pass> -keypass <pass>`

[image: console.developers.google.com oauth client]
[image: console.developers.google.com oauth consent screen]
[image: console.developers.google.com oauth scopes a]
[image: console.developers.google.com oauth scopes b]
[image: console.developers.google.com oauth scopes c]
[image: console.developers.google.com oauth scopes d]
[image: wearos screenshot account]
[image: wearos screenshot scope auth a]
[image: wearos screenshot scope auth b]
[image: wearos screenshot scope auth c]

full log in logcat:

```
Error:
2020-11-15 15:16:38.956 10288-10288/package_name I/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: start()
2020-11-15 15:16:38.957 10288-10288/package_name I/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: checkPermissionsAndRun
2020-11-15 15:16:38.957 10288-10288/package_name I/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: permissionApproved
2020-11-15 15:16:38.958 10288-10288/package_name I/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: runningQOrLater, permissionApproved true
2020-11-15 15:16:38.958 10288-10288/package_name I/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: fitSignIn
2020-11-15 15:16:39.152 10288-10288/package_name I/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: startRecording()
2020-11-15 15:16:39.767 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 0 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.activity.segment[activity(i)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.768 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 1 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.speed[speed(f)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.768 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 2 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.heart_rate.bpm[bpm(f)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.768 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 3 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.step_count.cadence[rpm(f)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.769 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 4 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.heart_minutes[intensity(f)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.769 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 5 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.active_minutes[duration(i)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.769 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 6 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.distance.delta[distance(f)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.769 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 7 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
2020-11-15 15:16:39.770 10288-10288/package_name E/RUN_FIT_GAME_WEAR: failRecording SUBSCRIBE i 8 dataTypeLen 9 dataType: DataType{com.google.calories.expended[calories(f)]}, error 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INVALID_ACCOUNT: null
```

Comment: I know this post is a bit old, but it might still be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295189/issue-with-google-fit-api-on-android-wear